# Receiving fatal error assigning QSharedPointer in QtTest

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsharedpointer, qttest

In TestGroup_Person, when I retrieve a QSharedPointer<-JB_TableRowProt> from JB_PersonDao and assign it to QSharedPointer<-JB_TableRowProt> aGroup_Person (in .h), I then get this error in the methods of TestGroup_Person.

Alternatively, if I retrieve  a QSharedPointer<-JB_TableRowProt> from JB_DaoProt in each method (and don't assign it to QSharedPointer<-JB_TableRowProt> aGroup_Person), it works fine.

Can someone explain to me why this assignment appears to be causing the error please?

I got this error:

```
QFATAL : TestGroup_Person::test_getDBTable_Name() Received signal 11
         Function time: 0ms Total time: 0ms
FAIL!  : TestGroup_Person::test_getDBTable_Name() Received a fatal error.
```

Here's the code:
main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QStringList arguments = QCoreApplication::arguments();

    QFile aFile(DATABASE_FILENAME);  // remove existing SP3.db
    if (aFile.exists())
        aFile.remove();

    map<QString, unique_ptr<QObject>> tests;
    tests.emplace("group_person", make_unique<TestGroup_Person>());


    if (arguments.size() >= 3 && arguments[1] == "-select") {
        QString testName = arguments[2];
        auto iter = tests.begin();
        while(iter != tests.end()) {
            if (iter->first != testName) {
                iter = tests.erase(iter);
            } else {
                ++iter;
            }
        }
        arguments.removeOne("-select");
        arguments.removeOne(testName);
    }

    int status = 0;

        for(auto& test : tests) {
            status |= QTest::qExec(test.second.get(), arguments);
        }

    return status;
    }
```

TestGroup_Person.h

```
#include <QString>
#include <QtTest>
#include <QSharedPointer>

#include "A_DB_Classes/JB_DatabaseManager.h"
#include "A_Tables/JB_Group_Person.h"

class TestGroup_Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestGroup_Person();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void test_allFieldsEqualsFieldNames();
    void test_getDBTable_FieldNames();
    void test_getDBTable_Name();
    void test_hasJoinTable();
    void test_setValueForField();
    void test_setStorageValueForField();
    void test_getStorageFields();

private:
    JB_DatabaseManager& mDB;
    QSharedPointer<JB_TableRowProt> aGroup_Person;
```

};

TestGroup_Person.cpp:

```
TestGroup_Person::TestGroup_Person():
mDB(JB_DatabaseManager::instance())
{
    aGroup_Person = mDB.aPersonDao.getJoinTableObject();
}

void TestGroup_Person::test_allFieldsEqualsFieldNames()
{
    const QVector<QString>& aVector = aGroup_Person->getDBTable_FieldNames();
    const QList<QString> aList = aGroup_Person->getAllFieldNames();
    bool isThere = true;
    QString fieldName = "";
    QString aResult = "This field name does not exist in all_FieldNamesAndValuesH";
    for (int i = 0; i < aVector.size() && isThere; ++i) {
        fieldName = aVector.at(i);
        isThere = aList.contains(aVector.at(i));
    }
    if (isThere)
        aResult = fieldName;
    QCOMPARE(fieldName, QString(aResult));
}

void TestGroup_Person::test_getDBTable_FieldNames()
{
    const QVector<QString>& aVector = aGroup_Person->getDBTable_FieldNames();
    QString fieldName = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < aVector.size(); ++i) {
        fieldName = fieldName + aVector.at(i) +",";
    }

    QVector<QString> fieldNames;
    QVector<QString> columnHeadings;
    aGroup_Person->getViewableFieldNamesAndHeadings(fieldNames, columnHeadings);
    bool correct = fieldNames.count() == columnHeadings.count();
    if (!correct)
        correct = columnHeadings.count() == 0;

    QCOMPARE(correct, true);
    QCOMPARE(fieldName,     QString("groupID,personID,jobID,grp_per_dateTimeStamp,"));
}

void TestGroup_Person::test_getDBTable_Name()
{
    QCOMPARE(aGroup_Person->getDBTable_Name(), QString("Group_Person"));
}
```

Relevant method of JB_DaoProt:

```
QSharedPointer<JB_TableRowProt> JB_DaoProt::getJoinTableObject()
{
    JB_TableRowProt* aJoinTable = new_JoinTableRowProt();
    QSharedPointer<JB_TableRowProt> pJoinTable(aJoinTable);
    return pJoinTable;
}
```

Comment: The error reported is related to TestPerson, not TestGroup_Person. Moreover, to init data members of a test class you should define the init() method, instead of the constructor. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html) you can find more details.

Comment: @GabriellaGiordano - I put the wrong error in. The same error came up for TestGroup_Person as well. I've edited the error message above to reflect this.

Comment: @GabriellaGiordano - Why init data members in the init() method instead of the constructor (I didn't see an explanation of this in your link). Is this what is causing the problem and why?

Comment: I moved initialising the QSharedPointer to the initTestCase() method and it now works. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what causes the difference please.

Comment: I can only make an educated guess: is new_JoinTableRowProt returning the same pointer for all the TestGroup_Person objects? And, if that's the case, is it possible that erasing one of the tests in the loop inside the main function, you invalidate all the references inside the shared pointers? Without a  [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is it very difficult to tell...